# Writing Apex Test class?

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch

```
global class UpdateStatusAcc implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {

    LogAccountTasks__c logAccTasks;
    Boolean flag = false;

    //List<Account> toUpdate;
    global String query;

    global UpdateStatusAcc() {
        query = 'SELECT Id, AccountId__c, AccRecordTypeId__c, AccRTDeveloperName__c, Etat_actuel_de_la_relation_geo__c,Etat_futur_de_la_relation_geo__c, Flag__c, Type_de_reseau__c, CreationDate__c FROM LogAccountTasks__c WHERE flag__c=false';
    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        //String query = 
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<LogAccountTasks__c> lstLogAccountTasks) {
        System.debug('Test');
        List<Id> accIds = new List<Id>();
        List<LogAccountTasks__c> lstTasks; //= new <List>logAccountTasks(); 
        List<Id> lstAccIds;
        //List<Account> TrigNew; 
        Map<id, Account> TrigoldMap;
        List<Account> lstmemoryAcc; 
        Account tmpAcc;

        if (lstLogAccountTasks == null || !lstLogAccountTasks.isEmpty()) {
                return;
        }
        System.debug('inside update');

        //Add the AccountId to the Ids List 
        for(LogAccountTasks__c LogAcc : lstLogAccountTasks) {
            //Prepare oldMap
            System.debug('inside new list');
            lstAccIds.add(LogAcc.AccountId__c);

            //Prepare List for simulate Trignew
            tmpAcc = null;
            tmpAcc.Id = LogAcc.AccountId__c;
            tmpAcc.Etat_relation_GEO__c = LogAcc.Etat_futur_de_la_relation_geo__c; 
            tmpAcc.RecordTypeId = LogAcc.AccRecordTypeId__c;
            tmpAcc.R_seau_int_gr__c = LogAcc.Type_de_reseau__c;
            lstmemoryAcc.add(tmpAcc);
            System.debug('update successful');
        }


        //create Account object List 
        //TrigNew = [SELECT Id, Name, RecordTypeID, R_seau_int_gr__c, Etat_relation_GEO__c FROM Account WHERE Id=:lstAccIds];

        //Create a virtual object of Account 
//      for(lstLogAccountTasks)

        //TrigoldMap = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id FROM Account], [SELECT Etat_relation_GEO__c FROM Account]);

        for (Account acc : [select Id, Etat_relation_GEO__c from Account  WHERE Id=:lstAccIds]) {
            System.debug('inside old map');
            TrigoldMap.put(acc.Id, acc);
        }
        UpdateStatus.hierarchyAccountDeploiment(lstmemoryAcc, TrigoldMap);
        UpdateStatus.hierarchyAccountTerminer(lstmemoryAcc, TrigoldMap);
        UpdateStatus.terminerFilByAccount(lstmemoryAcc);
/*      if (logAccountTasks != null && logAccountTasks.size() > 0) {
            for (Account a : logAccountTasks)
                 a.Etat_relation_GEO__c = 'Déploiement';
        }
*/
//      update logAccountTasks;
//      flag=true;

    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        //if(flag == true && logAccountTasks != null && logAccountTasks.size() > 0)
        //  delete logAccountTasks;
        //System.debug('hello');
    }

}
```

where my test is

```
@isTest
private class UpdateStatusAccTest {

    @isTest(seeAllData=true) static void test_updateStatusAcc() {



        List<LogAccountTasks__c> lstAccountTasks = new List<LogAccountTasks__c>();

            String aId = '012D00000002qdE'; // '00561000001DTdh';
            String siege_DeveloperName = 'X0_Si_ge_Centrale';
            LogAccountTasks__c logAccountTask;
            Map<Id, Account> oldMap;  
            Id MyId; 
            Account myAccount;

            //0123E00000006VZQAY

        // Implement test code


            List<Account> lstTestAcc = [SELECT Id, Name, RecordTypeId, RecordType.DeveloperName, Etat_relation_geo__c, R_seau_int_gr__c FROM Account WHERE RecordType.DeveloperName=:siege_DeveloperName AND Etat_relation_geo__c='Terminé' LIMIT 4];

            // TEST SUR statut "Déploiement"
            for(Account myacc : lstTestAcc) {
                logAccountTask = new LogAccountTasks__c();
                logAccountTask.Name =myacc.Name;
                logAccountTask.AccRecordTypeId__c = myacc.RecordTypeid; 
                logAccountTask.AccRTDeveloperName__c = myacc.RecordType.DeveloperName;
                logAccountTask.AccountId__c = myacc.Id;
                logAccountTask.Etat_actuel_de_la_relation_geo__c = 'Terminé';
                logAccountTask.Etat_futur_de_la_relation_geo__c = 'Déploiement';
                logAccountTask.Flag__c = false;
                logAccountTask.CreationDate__c =  DateTime.now();
                logAccountTask.Type_de_reseau__c = myacc.R_seau_int_gr__c;              
                lstAccountTasks.add(logAccountTask);
            }

             //TEST SUR statut "Terminé"
            lstTestAcc = [SELECT Id, Name, RecordTypeId, RecordType.DeveloperName, Etat_relation_geo__c, R_seau_int_gr__c FROM Account WHERE RecordType.DeveloperName=:siege_DeveloperName AND Etat_relation_geo__c='Déploiement' LIMIT 4];
            for(Account myacc : lstTestAcc) {
                logAccountTask = new LogAccountTasks__c();
                logAccountTask.Name =myacc.Name;
                logAccountTask.AccRecordTypeId__c = myacc.RecordTypeid; 
                logAccountTask.AccRTDeveloperName__c = myacc.RecordType.DeveloperName;
                logAccountTask.AccountId__c = myacc.Id;
                logAccountTask.Etat_actuel_de_la_relation_geo__c = 'Déploiement';
                logAccountTask.Etat_futur_de_la_relation_geo__c = 'Terminé';
                logAccountTask.Flag__c = false;
                logAccountTask.CreationDate__c =  DateTime.now();
                logAccountTask.Type_de_reseau__c = myacc.R_seau_int_gr__c;              
                lstAccountTasks.add(logAccountTask);
            }


            insert lstAccountTasks;


           // logAccountTask logAccTask = new LogAccountTasks__c(Id = lstAccountTasks[0].Id, AccountId__c = lstAccountTasks[])
           List<Id> myList = new List<Id>();
           for(LogAccountTasks__c logTask : lstAccountTasks){
                myList.add(logTask.AccountId__c);
           }

         Test.startTest();  

        UpdateStatusAcc updateSatusAcc = new UpdateStatusAcc();
        updateSatusAcc.query = 'SELECT Id, AccountId__c, AccRecordTypeId__c, AccRTDeveloperName__c, Etat_actuel_de_la_relation_geo__c,Etat_futur_de_la_relation_geo__c, Flag__c, Type_de_reseau__c, CreationDate__c FROM LogAccountTasks__c WHERE flag__c=false Limit 200';
        ID idBatch = Database.executeBatch(updateSatusAcc, 200);

        Test.stopTest();

        //    System.assertEquals(200, numShares); 
        System.assert(!lstAccountTasks.isEmpty());
        List<Account> lstAcc = [SELECT Id, Name, RecordTypeId, RecordType.DeveloperName, Etat_relation_geo__c, R_seau_int_gr__c from Account limit 1];
        SysteM.assertNotEquals(null,lstAcc[0].Id);
        System.assert(!lstACC.isEmpty());
            //System.assert(!lstAccIds.isEmpty());
        for(LogAccountTasks__c logAccTask : lstAccountTasks){
            System.assertNOTEquals(logAccTask.AccountId__c,null);
        }

        System.debug('test_updateStatusAcc ('+ idBatch +') : simulation tasks ');


   }
}
```

which does not cover following code

```
for(LogAccountTasks__c LogAcc : lstLogAccountTasks) {
            //Prepare oldMap
            System.debug('inside new list');
            lstAccIds.add(LogAcc.AccountId__c);

            //Prepare List for simulate Trignew
            tmpAcc = null;
            tmpAcc.Id = LogAcc.AccountId__c;
            tmpAcc.Etat_relation_GEO__c = LogAcc.Etat_futur_de_la_relation_geo__c; 
            tmpAcc.RecordTypeId = LogAcc.AccRecordTypeId__c;
            tmpAcc.R_seau_int_gr__c = LogAcc.Type_de_reseau__c;
            lstmemoryAcc.add(tmpAcc);
            System.debug('update successful');
        }


        //create Account object List 
        //TrigNew = [SELECT Id, Name, RecordTypeID, R_seau_int_gr__c, Etat_relation_GEO__c FROM Account WHERE Id=:lstAccIds];

        //Create a virtual object of Account 
//      for(lstLogAccountTasks)

        //TrigoldMap = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id FROM Account], [SELECT Etat_relation_GEO__c FROM Account]);

        for (Account acc : [select Id, Etat_relation_GEO__c from Account  WHERE Id=:lstAccIds]) {
            System.debug('inside old map');
            TrigoldMap.put(acc.Id, acc);
        }
        UpdateStatus.hierarchyAccountDeploiment(lstmemoryAcc, TrigoldMap);
        UpdateStatus.hierarchyAccountTerminer(lstmemoryAcc, TrigoldMap);
        UpdateStatus.terminerFilByAccount(lstmemoryAcc);
```

How can I cover these lines?

Comment: Avoid `seeAllData=true`, it would query records from database as well; thus throwing exception. Refer trailhead module- [Use Batch Apex](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/asynchronous_apex/units/async_apex_batch)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your unit test is telling you that your batch class has an error in it:

```
    if (lstLogAccountTasks == null || !lstLogAccountTasks.isEmpty()) {
            return;
    }
```

You're saying if the list is *not* empty, then return; it will *always* be not empty, because that's how batchable classes work. You can remove those three lines of code, because the list will never be null nor empty.

You also have a bunch of non-logical assertions laying around:

```
    SysteM.assertNotEquals(null,lstAcc[0].Id);
```

Id will never be null for a record queried from the database (except for a few certain objects that you'll likely never test in a unit test), but beyond that, you're basically just writing tests that are testing the system library and not your own code.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox for you reply shall I write test for my code how ?

Comment: @Veerpal You already wrote a unit test, correct? Start from where you left off.